# How to group and sort variables that are linked together

Tags: php

Brief idea of what I'm doing  is taking lines of writing that are always in same format which I'm using

```
    $result = $_POST['result'];
$result = explode(" ",$result);

foreach($result as $k => $v){
   ${"var".$k} = $v;
}
$var11 = trim($var11, "(");
$var18 = trim($var18, "(");
$var25 = trim($var25, "(");
$var32 = trim($var32, "(");
```

and then picking out the variables I need  to insert into my database

The format  of the text string

[18:20:23]  Neptune> At [18:20] on Table 40: SassyNClassy  G( 4 - 288 ) TipMeGood  B( 1 - 174 ) StandUpMan  Y( 0 - 23 ) Ruby2017  R( 0 - 10 )

varaibles below

Which echos out into these variables

```
$var1 = [18:20:23]
$var8 = 40:
$var9 = SassyNClassy
$var11 = G
$var12 = 4
$var14 = 288
$var16 = TipMeGood
$var18 = B
$var19 = 1
$var21 = 174
$var23 = StandUpMan
$var25 = Y
$var26 = 0
$var28 = 23
$var30 = Ruby2017
$var32 = R
$var33 = 0
$var35 = 10
```

Now what I am looking for is if it is possible how would I go about linking variables  Green (9 11 12 14)    blue (16 18 19 21)  yellow (23 25 26 28) red (30 32 33 35)

and reordering them  so that its blue green red yellow keeping in mind the order of colours changes based on the string input

I will be doing a input into my table which I can do but I need to  have it all in same order for other php code I'm in process of writing to add the 3rd variable of (blue and green) and of (red and yellow) as well as the scores of those 2 teams

UPDATED

Here are a few examples of what are posted via

```
 $result = $_POST['result'];
```

[18:20:23]  Neptune> At [18:20] on Table 40: SassyNClassy  G( 4 - 288 ) TipMeGood  B( 1 - 174 ) StandUpMan  Y( 0 - 23 ) Ruby2017  R( 0 - 10 )

What it should be in order
TipMeGood  B 1  174   SassyNClassy  G 4  288  StandUpMan  Y 0 23 Ruby2017 R 0 10

[18:21:50]  Neptune> At [18:21] on Table 35: oldstray  Y( 4 - 288 ) MeanyBritches  R( 2 - 188 ) racing_2425  B( 0 - 60 ) ladyhawk__  G( 0 - 20 )

What it should be in order
racing_2425  B 0  60  ladyhawk__  G 0  20 MeanyBritches  R 2 - 188 oldstray Y 4  288

[18:22:01]  Neptune> At [18:22] on Table 25: junesnugglebug  R( 4 - 288 ) WhamBam_Booty  G( 2 - 213 ) Misfitting  B( 2 - 178 ) kfallsgrl  Y( 0 - 137 )

What it should be in order
Misfitting  B 2  178  WhamBam_Booty  G 2  213  junesnugglebug  R 4  288 kfallsgrl  Y 0  137

Comment: Show us what the original input in `$_POST['result']` is

Comment: added 3 examples of what is passed through that shows  what is  in the 

     $_POST['result']  
and as you can see the predictions of order can be any of 24 combinations